# ECS & OpenGL Deferred Rendering

Tags: c#, opengl, game-engine, opentk

I'm currently designing a game engine in C# using OpenTK. I'm at the point where I've implemented the core design for deferred rendering, great!

However, I've put myself in a bit of pickle. Since deferred rendering requires me to do a geometry pass, and then the lighting pass I've realised that my original component based architecture won't be the best for deferred rendering, and this is why:

My rendering engine currently has a Render method, which takes in the game object to render. Any game object can have any number of child game objects and also any number of components (like Unity3D). Because of this, it's only natural to want different types of lights to be components. This way I can have directional, point and spot light components and a lights position is the position of the game object it's attached to.

The issue with this should be clear now, I render the game object by calling gameObject.Render(this) inside the rendering engine, which calls the render method of everyone of it's children and components, including it's light components. But because I have to do deferred rendering in two passes, the light components will never be rendered.

Because of this I have thought of one solution, but I'm not sure if it's a good or safe one:

First, I render all the game objects as normal, then during the render cycle, I add every light component in the game, to a list of lights in the rendering engine. Then I render the scene using the lights of lights, and once I'm done with the lights, I clear the list.

The approach would look a bit like this:

```
    public void Render(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        // Clear the lights to start over
        lights.Clear();

        // Do the geometry pass, 
        ClearScreen();
        gBufferFBO.Bind();

        // Inside the render method is where I would add the light to
        // the list of lights
        gameObject.Render(this);

        gBufferFBO.Unbind();

        // Render the lights
        RenderLights();
    }
```

Is this a safe approach? What other route can I take to integrate a component based design with deferred rendering?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work? If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: It works, however I'm just not sure whether or not it's a safe approach, adding to and clearing lists 120 times a second?

Comment: If your lights are static in the scene, why add/remove to a list per frame?

Comment: My lights aren't static

Comment: safe in which sense? It will not produce a memory leak or something like that. But in general asking for improvements or suggestions on working code is not exactly what SO is meant for.

Comment: Whilst a game is running, you want to avoid allocating memory (particularly .NET < v4) that will be discarded soon.  It's detrimental to performance.  AAA game designers allocate all memory at start of level.  I'd allocate an array once; maintain your own usage counters and just write over the elements.  https://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1500022979&sr=8-2&keywords=game+engine+architecture